# Spotipy - set CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET

Tags: python, spotify, getenv, spotipy

Where do I go to set CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET so it's not stored in my python script?  The Spotipy documentation says the following, but I can't figure out where I need to go to input these environment variables.  Where do I set os.getenv?

```
    if not client_id:
        client_id = os.getenv('SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID')

    if not client_secret:
        client_secret = os.getenv('SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET')

    if not client_id:
        raise SpotifyOauthError('No client id')

    if not client_secret:
        raise SpotifyOauthError('No client secret')
```

Comment: Those are operating system environment variables. It will depend on your OS where you would set those.

Answer (score 2):

On windows you can set your enviroment variables openning your cmd, change your directory to where your .py file is saved using `cd C:\example\example` then use `SET SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID=clientIDhere` and `SET SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET=secretHere` to set your variables.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what environment you're running in. Environmental variables are variables provided by the operating system, sitting outside the process you're calling them from. If you're in Linux, you would run something like:

```
export SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID=yourspotifyclientid
export SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET=yourspotifyclientsecret
```

You can get more info on environmental variables [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable).

Answer (score 0):

For windows 10 powershell terminal, use $env: and put your string code in quotes, worked for me.

```
$env:SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID="XXXX"
```