# Invalid character "\u24" in tokenPylance with Spotipy environment variables

Tags: python, spotipy

I want to make environment variables and I was looking at the documentation of Spotipy and it says that instead of "export," I have to use "$env:" because i'm on a windows system.

When I did change it though, I keep getting this error:

"Invalid character "\u24" in tokenPylance" specifically on all $env

I tried removing the $ from the env, and I tried running it with the directory in my powershell but I get ann erro saying that it is not recognized as anything either

Here is my code so far (actual ID's are redacted):

```
$env: SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID="xxxxxxxx"
$env: SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET="xxxxxxxxxx"
$env: SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI ="xxxxxxxxx"
$env: GENIUS_ACCESS_TOKEN ="xxxxxxxxx"
```

Any idea on why $env: is causing an error already in my program?

Answer (score 0):

The `\u24` refers to the `'$'` character.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57251904/827263), there can't be a space after the `:` character:

```
$env:SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID="xxxxxxxx"
$env:SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET="xxxxxxxxxx"
$env:SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI ="xxxxxxxxx"
$env:GENIUS_ACCESS_TOKEN ="xxxxxxxxx"
```

This is the PowerShell syntax for environment variables, documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.3).